# Drawing a boxplot of a Panda dataframe with time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, boxplot

I have a Panda Dataframe with the following data:

```
df1[['interval','answer']]

     interval       answer
0  0 days 06:19:17.767000           no
1  0 days 00:26:35.867000           no
2  0 days 00:29:12.562000           no
3  0 days 01:04:36.362000           no
4  0 days 00:04:28.746000          yes
5  0 days 02:56:56.644000          yes
6  0 days 00:20:13.600000           no
7  0 days 02:31:17.836000           no
8  0 days 02:33:44.575000           no
9  0 days 00:08:08.785000           no
10 0 days 03:48:48.183000           no
11 0 days 00:22:19.327000           no
12 0 days 00:05:05.253000     question
13 0 days 01:08:01.338000  unsubscribe
14 0 days 15:10:30.503000           no
15 0 days 11:09:05.824000           no
16 1 days 12:56:07.526000           no
17 0 days 18:10:13.593000           no
18 0 days 02:25:56.299000           no
19 2 days 03:54:57.715000           no
20 0 days 10:11:28.478000           no
21 0 days 01:04:55.025000          yes
22 0 days 13:59:40.622000          yes
```

The format of the df is:

```
id                   object
datum        datetime64[ns]
datum2       datetime64[ns]
answer               object
interval    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

As a result the boxplot looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh8aZ.png)

Any idea?

Any help is appreciated...

Robert

Answer (score 0):

[`Seaborn`](https://pypi.org/project/seaborn/) may help you achieve what you want.

First of all, one needs to make sure the columns are of the type one wants.

In order to recreate your problem, created the same dataframe (and gave it the same name `df1`). Here one can see the data types of the columns

```
[In]: df1.dtypes
[Out]:
interval      object
answer        object
dtype: object
```

For the column "answers", one can use [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) as follows

```
df1['NewAnswer'] = pd.factorize(df1['answer'])[0] + 1
```

That will create a new column and assign the values 1 to No, 2 to Yes, 3 to Question, 4 to Unscribe.

With this, one can, already, create a box plot using [`sns.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) as

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x="interval", y="NewAnswer", hue="answer", data=df1)
```

Which results in the following

[image]

The amount of combinations one can do are various, so I will leave only these as OP didn't specify its requirements nor gave an example of the expected output.

---

Notes:

1. Make sure you have the required libraries installed.
2. There may be other visualizations that would work better with these dataframe, [here one can see a gallery with examples](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html).

Comment: First of all thanks.

Unfortunately, there is an error:
"Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric."

x is a time interval
y is a value

Comment: id                   object
datum        datetime64[ns]
datum2       datetime64[ns]
answer               object
interval    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object

Comment: Dear Goncalo, thanks again. I added the format to the question.

Comment: @Robert_the_Python in the plot you shared there's just the axis. It seems that you may need to think this through properly and, if that's the case, post a different question.